# checkbox in kendoui treeview

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Is it possible to have a tree structure with check boxes in kendoui treeview. I did not find any thing in demos.

I wanted something similar this image which i upload image: Is there any alternative way we can achieve this?

I am using Kendoui treeview in this i need chekboxes for both parent and child,

when i click on parent, child also should be get selected,

and if i click on child it should display it's node id and parentid,

if i click multiple checkboxes they should display their id's and when i click on delete button all the mutiple selected checked nodes should be removed dynamically.

Please can you provide me any sample code (or) related example.

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 0):

It is implemented already from the Kendo UI team:

http://demos.kendoui.com/web/treeview/checkboxes.html

As for the id display,you can check:

http://demos.kendoui.com/web/treeview/events.html

and add an alert on select.